# How do I ssh from OSX Lion to Ubuntu GUI?

Tags: macos, ssh

I want to SSH from my Macbook to an ubuntu machine located on a domain in the form of xxx.ri.cmu.edu (I have a username and password to connect to it) but I want to view the GUI and not just the command-line interface that I could have sshed into using terminal. Are there any programs for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can SSH with the -X switch (X-forwarding)

You can then load up commands that require a GUI and they will display on your Mac.

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but you're technically asking for a Remote Desktop connection, which, to the best of my knowledge, is not available via SSH

Comment: Would Oracle Virtualbox work for GUI login?

Comment: I don't understand that question. Try connecting with a straight-up Remote Desktop connection or try a VNC connection from the macbook using the ssh details you have.

Comment: How do I connect using a Remote Desktop connection?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a clueless freshman new to all this :(

Comment: push apple+K and then type in vnc://IPADDRESS/